# VMWare, Cannot ping Linux guest from Windows 10 host in a wireless network: How do I disable a NDIS 6 Filter Driver?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, vmware

I have the same problem as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613949/vmware-cannot-ping-linux-guest-from-windows-10-host-over-bridged-connection.: a VM (Ubuntu-VM in VMWare Player on Windows host) connected in bridged mode is not accessable from the host when the host ist connected to the LAN wireless. As soon as I connect the host to the LAN via ethernet cable and after the new IP-Address is assigned all works fine.
The solution suggested is to disable a certain NDIS Filter driver ("LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver").

How is this done?
I found nothing, neither in the properties of the wireless network adapter (Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC7265) nor in "Network & Internet Settings".

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as I connect the host to the LAN via Ethernet cable and after
> the new IP-Address is assigned all works fine.

I have VMware, Ubuntu VM, and wireless network. All works fine wired or wireless.  I don't think it is valuable to be changing the NDIS properties at least until checking the obvious settings.

Make sure your Wireless connection is not set on Public.

Make sure for wireless that Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are both on.

Make sure for wireless that Password protected sharing is enabled. That is, make sure all sharing setting are set for wireless as well as wired.

Try pinging Windows from Linux.

Update the Wireless driver.

Check Wireless Isolation in your router (your VM is on a Bridged Connection) and disable Wireless Isolation if it is ON.

Restart the host machine, and try pinging the Ubuntu guest again.

If you wish to disable QOS, that setting is in the Properties of the Intel wireless card (both my Intel cards on both machines.  Control Panel, Network and Sharing, Network Connections, select your card, right click, Properties and QOS is there.

Also check the QOS setting in your Router (your VM connection is bridged).

Comment: I be am not certain but I will look around some more

Comment: veryfied all your points. But still: I can ping all machines on the LAN (another windows-host, another Ubuntu-VM on that host) from the VM except its own host. And the other way round: from the wireless-connected host I can ping all other machines except the own guest-VM.

Comment: For my Intel wireless cards, QOS is a setting in the card properties.  Control Panel, Network and Sharing, Network Connections, select your card, right click, Properties and QOS is there.  (2) look at your Router wireless settings - mine includes a QOS setting.   Also make sure in your router that Wireless Isolation is not ON,  That may affect your wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: In "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" I found the the wireless conection was bridged. Taking it from the bridge solved my problem.